# volume shadow copy always fails

Tags: windows, shadow-copy

Starting from last December, I cannot make any shadow copies. Everything which uses shadow copies, including Windows backup, System Restore and online disk check fails. My system is running Windows 8 Pro upgraded from Windows 7 Home Premium, and my system drive previously had BitLocker on but recently turned off. Whenever I try to create a shadow copy, it fails and the following error is shown in the event log:

Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Error calling a routine on a Shadow Copy Provider {b5946137-7b9f-4925-af80-51abd60b20d5}. Routine details EndPrepareSnapshots({xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}) [hr = 0x800706be, The remote procedure call failed.
].

Operation:
   Executing Asynchronous Operation

Context:
   Current State: DoSnapshotSet

The xxxx is stuff which is different each time, but all the others are the same every time. The event ID is 12293 and the source is VSS.

After I tried operation, some writers timed out as follows, on a fresh boot, there is no error at the beginning.

```
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2012 Microsoft Corp.

Writer name: 'Task Scheduler Writer'
   Writer Id: {d61d61c8-d73a-4eee-8cdd-f6f9786b7124}
   Writer Instance Id: {1bddd48e-5052-49db-9b07-b96f96727e6b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'VSS Metadata Store Writer'
   Writer Id: {75dfb225-e2e4-4d39-9ac9-ffaff65ddf06}
   Writer Instance Id: {088e7a7d-09a8-4cc6-a609-ad90e75ddc93}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Performance Counters Writer'
   Writer Id: {0bada1de-01a9-4625-8278-69e735f39dd2}
   Writer Instance Id: {f0086dda-9efc-47c5-8eb6-a944c3d09381}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'System Writer'
   Writer Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Writer Instance Id: {c88a5c02-754b-452d-8252-6b1dfa95a77c}
   State: [7] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'ASR Writer'
   Writer Id: {be000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4}
   Writer Instance Id: {174e7659-18bb-4cf3-99e7-4684e138725b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Registry Writer'
   Writer Id: {afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}
   Writer Instance Id: {087d01f7-fa2c-45b4-8947-a529a1266641}
   State: [7] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'SqlServerWriter'
   Writer Id: {a65faa63-5ea8-4ebc-9dbd-a0c4db26912a}
   Writer Instance Id: {925e2dfc-a158-476f-9373-6c41297a7c6b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'IIS Config Writer'
   Writer Id: {2a40fd15-dfca-4aa8-a654-1f8c654603f6}
   Writer Instance Id: {bc33ce04-4072-4b73-b7a8-01ab67c9910a}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Shadow Copy Optimization Writer'
   Writer Id: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
   Writer Instance Id: {b97ac783-5c9b-43f0-afe5-4b4f5f707a7b}
   State: [7] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'COM+ REGDB Writer'
   Writer Id: {542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}
   Writer Instance Id: {ab06a043-0113-470c-abe5-0d18c44eb2d2}
   State: [7] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'WMI Writer'
   Writer Id: {a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}
   Writer Instance Id: {e237d43c-3f14-4650-b3d2-3ea7c2056822}
   State: [7] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'MSSearch Service Writer'
   Writer Id: {cd3f2362-8bef-46c7-9181-d62844cdc0b2}
   Writer Instance Id: {ca224d2c-cb60-46ad-8cfd-66fa9cb40a03}
   State: [7] Failed
   Last error: Timed out

Writer name: 'MSMQ Writer (MSMQ)'
   Writer Id: {7e47b561-971a-46e6-96b9-696eeaa53b2a}
   Writer Instance Id: {529a6372-85eb-4398-b80a-5268e749b946}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few attempts of unsuccessfully installing Windows last night, the shadow copies work again. I think that forcing a check of C: helped.

P.S. After a while, the problem reappeared. The cause is now the SoftPerfect RAM Disks. After I removed them, it works again.

Comment: After checking the disk, my system has become much faster.